# PHP - stream crypto enabled server cuts off bytes

Tags: php, websocket, stream, php-stream-wrappers

I made a WebSocket server with PHP and added the feature to add SSL/TLS to the server. Now I enabled crypto with stream_socket_enable_crypto and everything works. I read data and it's decrypted. Only HTTP requests are a bit weird:

Client sends:

```http
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0
Accept: */*
...
```

Server receives:

```http
 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0
Accept: */*
...
```

My Questions are: What is the reason for the missing bytes? What can I do to get those bytes back?

I use PHP 8.2

**Server:**

Terminal:

```bash
openssl genrsa -out wss.key 2048 && openssl req -key wss.key -new -x509 -days 365 -out wss.crt
```

PHP:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

if(ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://example.com:8080", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN);

stream_context_set_option($server, ["ssl" => [
    "local_cert" => __DIR__."/wss.crt",
    "local_pk" => __DIR__."/wss.key",
    "disable_compression" => true,
    "verify_peer" => false,
    "verify_peer_name" => false,
    "allow_self_signed" => true
]]);

$done = false;
while(!$done) {
    $sockets = ["server" => $server];

    if(stream_select($sockets, $w, $e, 0, 20) === false)
        show("ERROR");

    if(in_array($server, $sockets)) {
        $client = stream_socket_accept($server);
        $sockets[] = $client;
        stream_socket_enable_crypto($client, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_SERVER);
    }

    foreach($sockets as $client) {
        if(!in_array($client, $sockets))
            continue;

        show(fread($client, 100));

        fclose($client);
        $done = true;
        show("EXIT");
    }
}

function show(...$data) {
    var_dump($data);
    @ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

**Client:**

JS:

```js
url = "ws://example.com:8080";
socket = new WebSocket(url);
setTimeout(() => {
    socket.close();
    socket = new WebSocket(url);
}, 1000);
```

Change `example.com:8080` with your host and port

for detailed code look at [PHPWS](https://gitlab.com/Playit3110/PHPWS)

Comment: The client is just the Browser with `new Websocket` and I already said that everthing works except the HTTP request on the SSL/TLS server, because 5 Bytes get missing. Also im right now about to post the code on gitlab

Comment: You mean you want to know where `GET / ` went? Please always try to be specific. And how are you actually logging this data at each end of the request? And what specific problem is this causing you?

Comment: @ADyson yeah. Im missing the `GET /`. I log it after I read it from `stream_get_contents`, but it also happens if I use `fread`. It's makes it difficult to read the path and to be sure its a valid HTTP request.

Comment: Ok. Can you at least provide us with a [mre] of the issue please (as per [ask]).

Comment: @ADyson at the link you can find the source code and the `stream_get_contents` is in `websocket.class.php:111`

Comment: I may need to remind you of the Stackoverflow guidance: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). External links can change or die over time, and so are not accepted here.

Comment: I added a small sample for other people, but please use the link for the entire source code, because it is an entire lib.

Comment: If we used that sample on its own, would we see the same problem? That's the acid test of a [mre]. If it doesn't, then build it up until it does. Otherwise this question might be worthless for future readers, if/when you go on to make any changes to your library code in github. Thanks.

Comment: It's just a thought, but GET is one of [the HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)... Not sure what I am implying with that, but perhaps it's special in some way, and therefore not part of the content you receive? Then again, this is a simple socket... so... forget it. No, it is a _websocket_, that must mean something? Oh, I don't know... just thinking aloud...

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I tested it with other methods and it still misses 5 characters (bytes). also to start a websocket you need http requests.

Comment: @ADyson now theres code to reproduce my problem. It shows exactly what i encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now know the issue. The TCP paylaod starts after `00 00` and in HTTP there begins the `GET /` and in TLS the `TLS headers`: `17 03 03 03 15` with the TLS DATA TYPE (Application Data `23`), the TLS VERSION (1.2 `03 03`) and the PAYLOAD LENGTH (789 `03 15`)

[image: HTTP Packet]

[image: TLS Packet]

In PHP after `stream_socket_enable_crypto` the first package is read as TLS and the first 5 bytes as the TLS headers and after failing, because its HTTP, it is missing those 5 bytes in the payload.

## **Solution:**

Before enabling crypto, read the data without clearing it from the buffer (PEEK)

```php
if(in_array($server, $sockets)) {
    $client = stream_socket_accept($server);
    $sockets[] = $client;

    $content = stream_socket_recvfrom($client, 5, STREAM_PEEK);

    stream_socket_enable_crypto($client, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_SERVER);
}
```

Now the data can be used if it's just a HTTP request and no TLS header information are missing when it's a TLS handshake.